# TestNg test is not running on kepler 4.3(eclipse) but junit4 is running

Tags: eclipse, selenium, junit, testng

I have eclipse with kepler 4.3 version, which i am using for selenium webdriver to test my gui application.

I have created a testNG test and tried to run as TestNG ,but,nothing is running and no error messages.

Environment which i am using:

- Eclipse: kepler 4.3
- selenium webdriver for java (2.43)
- JDk 1.7(JSee 1.7)

I created other project with junit and executed successfully for the same configuration.

Can you please some one help me ,why testNG is not working on kepler?

Will TestNG supports kepler?

Comment: It supports. Could you share your code with us?

Comment: public static void Navigate(){
File file = new File("C:/Driver/iexploredriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("sampl.com")
}